# How to add additional .jar to JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6] in VSCode?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, applet

I have a Java applet project that some of the package unable to be recognized in VSCode.

[image]

It because the project doesn't import `plugin.jar` and I can't see it in `JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6]`.

[image]

I'm sure the `plugin.jar` exists in my `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\jre\lib` folder.

[image]

How can I add this `plugin.jar` to the list?

By the way, I'm using Maven and I have a `pom.xml` file. Here is it's content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>my-app</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>big5</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The original answer failed to solve the problem, the updated answer is as follows:

Use the following command to add a local `.jar` package to the maven local repository.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

After the addition is successful, modify the `pom.xml` file to add dependencies.

```xml
 <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-id</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-id</artifactId>
      <version>version</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

---

---

**original answer**

This class should be stored in the `jrt-fs.jar` under the Java folder. I have tried several versions of java ([downloaded and installed from the official website](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/archive/)), all of which include this file by default.

[image]

[image]

*Even if you delete a `jrt-fs.jar` under a certain version, vscode will automatically reference jar files under other versions.*

**So I think a better solution is to use the Java version provided by the official website.**

##### As far as the question you asked. You can add the `.jar` as follows:

Since your project is built by maven, you can see these two dependency managers in the **JAVA PROJECTS** panel:

[image]

Of course, you can't change the system library, so you can only add dependencies for maven,

1. Click the plus sign on the right side of **Maven Dependencies**,

   [image]
2. type in the package name you want to add and search for it.

   [image]
3. Choose a library to add it.

   [image]

*This modifies the following in your `pom.xml` file.*

```xml
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.30</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

*If it's just a normal Java project, click the plus sign to the right of **Referenced Libraries** and add the jar in the file manager.*

[image]

[image]